# Message: Undefined variable and Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Help me.. I am getting error **Message: Undefined variable: pegawai** and **Message: Invalid argument for foreach()** in my View. I wanted to display all entries in my mysql table but i kept on getting error message. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this.

My controllers

```
<?php

    class Perolehan_Dana extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            //checkAksesModule();
            if($this->session->userdata('id_user') != TRUE){
            redirect(base_url(''));
            exit;
            };
            $this->load->helper(array('url'));
            $this->load->library('ssp');
            $this->load->model('model_perolehan_dana');
        }

        function pegawai($value='')
        {

            $data = array('data'  =>$this->model_perolehan_dana->pegawai(),);
            tpl('perolehan_dana/view', $data);
        }

}
```

My model

```
<?php

    class Model_perolehan_dana extends CI_Model
    {

        public $table = "tbl_perolehan_dana";

        function pegawai()
        {
            return $this->db->query("SELECT * from tbl_perolehan_dana a, tbl_sumber_dana b, tbl_jenis_dana c where a.sumber_dana=b.id_sumber_dana AND c.id_sumber_dana=a.jenis_dana group by a.id");
        }

    }

?>
```

My view

```
<?php $no=1; foreach($pegawai as $admin): ?>
       <tr>
       <td><?= $no ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['sumber_dana'] ?></td> 
       <td><?= $admin['jenis_dana'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['tahun_anggaran'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['jml_rp'] ?></td>
       <td><a href="<?= base_url('admin/pegawai_edit/'.$admin['id']) ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> <a href="<?= base_url('admin/pegawai_hapus/'.$admin['id']) ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a></td> 
       </tr>
       <?php $no++; endforeach; ?>
```

Please help me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try below code**
Controller:

```
function pegawai($value='')
{
   $data = array();
   $data['pegawai'] = $this->model_perolehan_dana->pegawai();
   tpl('perolehan_dana/view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function pegawai()
{
   return $this->db->query("SELECT * from tbl_perolehan_dana a, tbl_sumber_dana b, tbl_jenis_dana c where a.sumber_dana=b.id_sumber_dana AND c.id_sumber_dana=a.jenis_dana group by a.id")->result_array();
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(!empty($pegawai)) { ?>
<?php $no=1; foreach($pegawai as $admin): ?>
       <tr>
       <td><?= $no ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['sumber_dana'] ?></td> 
       <td><?= $admin['jenis_dana'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['tahun_anggaran'] ?></td>
       <td><?= $admin['jml_rp'] ?></td>
       <td><a href="<?= base_url('admin/pegawai_edit/'.$admin['id']) ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> <a href="<?= base_url('admin/pegawai_hapus/'.$admin['id']) ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a></td> 
       </tr>
       <?php $no++; endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
```